# TRIED ALMOST EVERYTHING: ypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

I am having this problem and cant get around it at all

im making a platform game for uni

i have 2 files

flashgame.fla and Coin.as (this is code for the Coin class)

i have code stating that once the player has collected all the coins the frame will change from frame 1 to frame 2. 
When i do i receive this message

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at Coin/update() TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot
>   access a property or method of a null object reference.   at
>   flashgame_fla::MainTimeline/loop()

i have tried Try and Catch and various other things

I think it does this because the Coin.as extends MovieClip so when it goes to the next frame it is still trying to find a coin when nothing is there.

here is the code for Coin.as

---

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;


public class Coin extends MovieClip {
    var player:MovieClip;
    var mainTimeLine = MovieClip(root);

    public function Coin() {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }

    function update(event:Event):void
    {
        player=MovieClip(root).player;
        if(this.hitTestObject(player))
        {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
            parent.removeChild(this);
            mainTimeLine.coinCount++;
        }

    }
}

}
```

i have an array in flashgame.fla that records all coins in the game. when the player hits them they are spliced from the array. could also be causing the problem when going to frame 2

important stuff from flashgame.fla

---

```
var coin:Array = new Array();
for (i=0; i<numChildren; i++)
{
    if (getChildAt(i) is Coin)
    {
        coin.push(getChildAt(i).getRect(this));
    }
}
```

---

splicing coins

---

```
for (i=0; i<coin.length; i++)
    {
        if (player.getRect(this).intersects(coin[i]))
        {
            coinSnd.play();
            coin.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help given
if you need anything more from me please ask :)
all g with screenshots

Comment: Addition!

When i add another frame or keyframe to the coin layer i no longer get the error but flash totally freezes -_-

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because the player cannot be found in the update function in the Coin class. This is because ENTER_FRAME events are run even if the display object is not on the stage, which you often don't want. In this case you try to do a hittest against the player.

To solve this, you can start running update as soon as the Coin is attached to the stage and stop running it as soon as it's removed from the stage.

```
public function Coin() {
   this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
   this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemovedFromStage);
}

function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void {
   this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
}

function onRemovedFromStage(event:Event):void {
   this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
}
```

Comment: I gave it a try and set it up the way you posted it with the update function below the rest of the code but still received the same error.

not sure if i setup the code wrong or if it doesnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

Which line number is the error occurring on? That should tell you which variable is null.

My guess, based on this part of the error: "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at Coin/update()", is that the `parent` of the coin is null because you've moved to a new keyframe and the instance has been removed from the stage.

That is, I suspect the error is occurring on the line with `parent.removeChild(this);` - is this correct?

If that's the case then check whether `parent` is not null before calling `removeChild` on it.

Comment: i think you maybe right
i have decided to try just continue the frames with the coin and player on it
i know its bad practive but this assignment needs to get done :)

Comment: But on which line is the error occurring - surely the error gives you the line number which you can match to the code itself?